# CASE statement: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'no ed is required' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `CASE` statement in my code, I want to have a string on the `ELSE '' END`but get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'no ed is required' to data type int.

This is my code:

```
SELECT
    [Ticket ID],
    [Request Type],
    MAX(maxBuild),
    (CASE     
        WHEN [edBuild Date Documented] IS NOT NULL
             AND [edBuild Date Documented] > MAX(maxBuild)  
           THEN (DATEDIFF(DAY, [edBuild Date Documented], MAX(maxVal))) 
           ELSE '' 
     END) AS 'Days took from edBuild to validation/if 0 no edbuild involved'
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         CreatedDateTime AS [ticket submitted],
         IncidentID AS [Ticket ID],
         [titleT],
         (CASE     
             WHEN OwnedbyTeamT = 'xxx' 
                  AND ClosedDateTimeT <> '1899-12-30 00:00:00.000' 
                  AND TitleT LIKE '%ed%Build' 
                  AND (TitleT NOT LIKE '%Dup%') 
                THEN (ClosedDateTimeT) 
                ELSE 'no ed is required' 
          END) AS 'edBuild Date Documented'    
     FROM
         TaskView  
     WHERE
         IncidentID = '2272516 ' OR IncidentID = '2221' OR IncidentID = '21211') AS tt 
GROUP BY
    [Ticket ID], [Request Type],
    [MedBuild Date Documented],
    MAX(maxBuild)
```

is there any way to resolve this error?

Thanks

Comment: cant you use null?

Comment: You can't store an int value and a varchar value in the same column of your subquery. Those are two different types. `edBuild Date Documented` has to be one or the other.

Comment: @Simonare, it works when I use ''. However, I want to show the end user this statement: no ed is required

Comment: @nina_dev - sorry tried to improve formatting of your code - but could not figure out how to reverse it. Had to manually tweak again. - as others have said the ' ' is the issue DATEDIFF in the THEN has to match type of ELSE part. Not sure if NULL would have been better option.

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the corrections

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't mix the datatype .. if the result is varchar  then cast the int to varchar too

```
THEN (CAST ClosedDateTimeT  AS VARCHAR) ELSE 'no ed is required' END) AS 'edBuild Date Documented'
```

for

```
THEN cast( (DATEDIFF(DAY, [edBuild Date Documented], MAX(maxVal))) as VARCHAR)  ELSE '' ....
```

Comment: I need this part "(DATEDIFF(DAY, [edBuild Date Documented], MAX(maxVal))) "  @scaisEdge

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `NULL` instead of `''`. `''` cannot be converted to `int` implicitly.

also if your result type is needed to be `int` you can use

```
SELECT CAST('' AS int);
```

result is `0`